# AWS SNS as source for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I have:

- CloudWatch rules that publish messages to a SNS topic
- A Lambda function that has SNS topic as its source

When a CloudWatch rule is triggered, it publishes its rule name to an SNS topic and then the Lambda function is invoked. The Lambda function goes ahead and deletes the CloudWatch rule that invoked the Lambda function based on the rule name passed to Lambda through SNS.

I have multiple rules that trigger on different schedules. The problem is is that one rule gets triggered but multiple rules get deleted. The Lambda function should only be invoked for that rule name.

Comment: Could you clarify *why* you are doing this? There might be a better way to achieve what you are seeking, rather than creating/deleting CloudWatch rules (which I assume are rules for CloudWatch Events). For example, why are you firing a rule based on a schedule, and then deleting the rule? Are you trying to run the rule only once? Can you provide your Lambda code? Have you checked the log files to confirm how many times the Lambda function is being triggered?

Comment: so here is what I am doing, my rules has multiple targets and they intended to send messages to sqs and sns topics so that other applications can consume. The rules are scheduled in different intervals such us every 1/2/3.. minutes or every 1/2/3.. hours and so on.  In some case the when consuming application receives the message it decides that this rule should only run once more then should be deleted, the consuming application calls the api and attach another target to same rule. This new target will be deleting the rule when it triggers again.

Comment: This new target is another SNS topic and its message is the rule name and a Lambda is the event source for this SNS topic. When the rule triggers, it has the new target and new target will invokes Lambda through SNS to delete the rule.

Comment: I have about +3k  rules running in different schedules. You may ask me why I use SNS to invoke Lambda and don't use Lambda directly as an additional target to the rule for deleting the rule. I tried that but AWS sdk is not supporting Lambda event source through cloudWatch and needs to be done through console. All my setup is an API based and I don't use console.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your responses, it sounds like deleting the rules is maybe not the optimal solution you're looking for? Would it be acceptable to simply disable the CloudWatch Event rule? If so, the method in the SDK is pretty straightforward[1] and would negate any need for you to programmatically recreate rules for the same intervals, you would simply need to reenable them using the same name.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html#disableRule-property

Comment: Maybe an option to try but the thing is rules are limited, by default its 50 rules per account and I increased it to 3K. I will see if enabling/disabling will do the job.